# How to define output format of raster calculator in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

Is it possible to define the format of my target raster in QGIS raster calculator?

I have an Int16 raster which becomes float after processing the following command:

`myraster@1>0`

As I'd like to use GDAL sieve (which only works with Integer rasters), it would be great not to change the raster format by hand again.

Comment: But Int16 is not fload. It is integer data type.

Comment: @ahmadhanb sorry to express myself unprecise. I have Int16, after raster calc its Float but I'd prefer it to be Int16 always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to use the raster calculator located under Processing Toolbox not the one located under Raster menu. There you can control the output type such as Int16 instead of Float:

From `Processing toolbar -> GDAL/OGR -> [GDAL]Miscellaneous -> Raster Calculator`

[image]

[image]